# blank the field on Submit (vee-validate vue)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router, vee-validate

I'm creating a form in **Vue** having validation of **Vee-validate**. I want to make field blank on submit. But it is giving an error when I make the field blank on submit.

Can someone please help me to sort out it?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code/ provide JsFiddle to resolve the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *You can add a small portion of code which describes better your problem.*

But you can do this with Vee-validate after submitting your form

```
this.yourField = ''
this.$validator.reset()
```

Comment: Thanks it working but also with it .. We have to make value of v-model blank.